# Elasticsearch painless sorting null_pointer_error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to create a sorting script with painless, filtering nested documents.
The reason I'm doing this with a script, is because I need to emulate a COALESCE statement.

My documents have titles stored like:

```
{
  title: [
    {
      type: MainTitle,
      value: [
        {
          language: eng,
          label: The title 
        },
        {
          language: ger,
          label: Das title 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: AvailabilityTitle,
      value: [
        {
          language: eng,
          label: New thing! 
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

title and title.value are nested documents.

I want to sort documents primarily by their english MainTitle and by their german MainTitle *only if* no english MainTitle exists - even if the german title gave a higher score.

I'm trying to simply sort by the english MainTitle first to try it out and this is the script:

```
def source = params._source;

def titles = source.title;
if (titles != null && titles.length > 0) {
    for(int i=0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        def t = titles[i];
        if (t.type == 'MainTitle') {
          
          def values = t.value;
          if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
              def v = values[j];
              if (v.language == 'eng') {

                return v.label;

              }
            }
          }
        
        }
    }
}

return \"\";
```

For some reason I'm getting a null_pointer_exception

```
"script_stack": [
  "if (values != null && values.length > 0) {       ",
  "                            ^---- HERE"
],
```

I don't get how values can be null at that point since I'm specifically checking for null just before it.

Comment: Interestingly, it is working correctly with your shared sample document.

Comment: So it has something to do with documents not having that field.... I thought I covered that with the null check

Comment: Yes. I think you did. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null_pointer_exception is thrown, not because `values` is null, but because `values` does not have a method/function called `length`. That is because for *some reason* `values` is an ArrayList even though `titles` earlier is an Array. Apparently they both have the method/function `size()` so I can just use that.

So this works:

```
def source = params._source;

def titles = source.title;
if (titles != null && titles.size() > 0) {
    for(int i=0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
        def t = titles[i];
        if (t.type == 'MainTitle') {
          
          def values = t.value;
          if (values != null && values.size() > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {
              def v = values[j];
              if (v != null && v.language == 'fin') {

                return v.label;

              }
            }
          }
        
        }
    }
}

return '';
```